# Script tag inside another script tag

Tags: javascript, tags

Is it possible to open and close a script tag inside another script tag?

#### Example

```
<script type="..." src="...">
code here
<script type="!!!" src="!!!">
code also here
</script>
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you even want that?

Answer (score 1):

No

If the parent script tag is for javascript then child `<script...` is invalid javascript (you can't have html inside javascript).

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `<script>` tag between a `<script>` and `</script>`, that script then will be treated as a JavaScript expression.

In most cases, that means it generates an error message like ...

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

... or ...

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

However, it doesn't generate an error per se. For example, consider the following code :

```
console.log('BEFORE');
var script = 0; var bool = 1 <script> 2;
console.log(bool);
console.log('AFTER');
```

This doesn't produce a code, because `1 <script> 2` is evaluated as this :

1. `1`
2. `is smaller than`
3. `script`
4. `is greater than`
5. `2`

Because `script` exists as a variable, that doesn't produce any error. In the code here-above, `console.log(bool);` outputs `false`.